# How to pretty print output for SqlAlChemy?

Tags: python, sql, printing, sqlalchemy

This is my code for SqlAlChemy after linking it to the database. I am trying to print the top IP address for the year 2017. However, i could not pretty print my results.

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func, and_, desc
import math

Top2017 = session.query(Log.IP,func.count(Log.IP).label('count')).filter(and_(Log.date >= '2017-1-1',Log.date <= '2017-12-31')).group_by(Log.IP).order_by(desc('count'))

print("The Top IP Address is   ")
print("Year" , "IP Address")
for q in Top2017.limit(3):
    print("2017", q)
```

My output is:

```
The Top IP Address is   
Year IP Address
2020-03-06 10:21:03,811 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT logfile."IP" AS "logfile_IP", count(logfile."IP") AS count 
FROM logfile 
WHERE logfile.date >= ? AND logfile.date <= ? GROUP BY logfile."IP" ORDER BY count DESC
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
2020-03-06 10:21:03,812 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('2017-1-1', '2017-12-31', 3, 0)
2017 ('10.131.0.1', 1921)
2017 ('10.130.2.1', 1805)
2017 ('10.128.2.1', 1667)
```

The output is very messy as the result is not very clear with all the queries printed. Hence, my desired output will be:

```
The Top IP Address is 

Year IP Address Count 
2017 10.131.0.1 1921
2017 10.130.2.1 1805
2017 10.128.2.1 1667
```

Thank you for your help.

This is the output for dict.

```
The Top IP Address is   
Year IP Address Count
OrderedDict([('10.131.0.1', 1921), ('10.130.2.1', 1805), ('10.128.2.1', 1667)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

Top2017 = (
    session.query(Log.IP, func.count(Log.IP).label("count"))
    .filter(and_(Log.date >= "2017-1-1", Log.date <= "2017-12-31"))
    .group_by(Log.IP)
    .order_by(desc("count"))
    .limit(3)
)

dict = OrderedDict(Top2017)
```

Now, you have the query result in a dictionary and can print the desired output from it like this:

```py
print("The Top IP Address is   ")
print("Year" , "IP Address", "Count")
for key, value in dict.items():
    print("2017", key, value)
```

Do let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Hello! i have this error -> 'int' object is not subscriptable at the for loop

Comment: can you add the output of `dict` in the question as well so that I can check for the change required.

Comment: I have added a change for the error, as value is a tuple so changed the way of extracting the individual elements.

Comment: Hi i have added the result of my output as shown above

Comment: I have printed the output.

Comment: I have changed  the code, now run it and let me know

Comment: Hi! omg yes i manage to get the output! but all this information is still there (2020-03-06 10:21:03,811 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT logfile."IP" AS "logfile_IP", count(logfile."IP") AS count 
FROM logfile 
WHERE logfile.date >= ? AND logfile.date <= ? GROUP BY logfile."IP" ORDER BY count DESC
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?) do you happen to know how to remove it ?

Comment: remove `print(dict)` if you have it. just use the code that I have mentioned, I think you are including your previous code as well.

Comment: I have removed, but it is still the same. Probably is the format for SqlAlChemy

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print result as a table, use tabulate package.

pip install tabulate

```
from tabulate import tabulate

q = engine.execute('SHOW DATABASES;')
result = q.fetchall()
print(tabulate(result, headers=q.keys(), tablefmt='psql'))
```

Comment: This worked well for me and seems better than the accepted answer.